# Access and VB, save value to string

Tags: sql, vb.net, string

So I want to save value to string and add 1 to that value, before putting it in database. Basicly something like this:

```
Dim sqlQuery As String
Dim lastEntry As String
Dim newEntry As String'this is lastEntry+1
sqlQuery = "SELECT MAX(ID) AS lastID FROM table"  'I selected the highest ID from database
```

How can I assign that selected value to string *lastEntry* and then add 1 to that value before saving it as *newEntry*?

In last step, I should use something like this:

```
dbtable("ID").Value = newEntry
```

Thanks for any help! :)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Why are you saving numbers to strings? One question at a time. Do some research to figure out the easy ones.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, every value in database is string. I'm using RegExp function to save values from file which I upload. I had AutoNumber field for ID at first, butthat didn't work anymore when I imported some data. That's why I want to create ID numbers programaticly, set new record to last ID from database + 1. My problem is that I don+t know how to store value I get from SQL query?

Comment: 1-Becarfull when asking for MAX() on a string that you think of as a number. (2 is greater than 123456789)  2-What do you mean by 'store value I get from SQL query'? Do you mean you want to store it in a table in the database or do you mean you don't know how to get it into a variable in VB so you can work with it?

Comment: I want to:
1. get MAX value from database
2. save that value to TEMP variable
3. add 1 to TEMP variable
4. save TEMP to new variable and send it to database along with other data. Or is there a simpler way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of inserting data into the table where the ID is TEXT but you want to get the max value numerically (not as text) and then insert into that table.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (ID,Field1)
SELECT TOP 1 MAX(VAL(ID)) + 1 as NextId, "Test" as Field1
FROM Table1;
```

The main thing to notice here is that I did a VAL() on the ID so it is treated as a number BEFORE getting the MAX(). Like I said in my comments, the text value of 2 is greater than anything that starts with a 1. That means 2 is greater than 123,456 when viewed as text.